# How is this Linux computer able to output video without a display connection?

Tags: usb, video, display, motherboard, hdmi

I bought a [Tempo Studio](https://tempo.fit/studio) a little over a year ago and love the weights but not the subscription software. I'd seen it fail into GRUB before and know it's Ubuntu-based PC and figured, how hard could it be to display my iPhone on it? I decided to crack it open.

[image]

All the cables, sans the thick one with the many different-colored strands at the bottom, are labeled, and none of them are video except one. The one HDMI cable runs from the video card into the motherboard. Unplugging the videocard > motherboard connection and into a display showed the interface, which what I would expect. I plugged in my laptop to the motherboard and my computer appeared (rotated 90 degrees, which I was able to fix).

This is where I got confused. I decided to take more of the machine apart to see what's behind the motherboard - I thought I perhaps was missing a cable, some other video out on the motherboard. There is nothing on the back of the motherboard other than a CMOS batter taped to it. I tried to dump the EDID of the display to do some digging.

```
 "_name" : "LED1920X1080",
          "_spdisplays_display-product-id" : "148",
          "_spdisplays_display-serial-number" : "1010101",
          "_spdisplays_display-vendor-id" : "4d6d",
          "_spdisplays_display-week" : "23",
          "_spdisplays_display-year" : "2020",
          "_spdisplays_displayID" : "3",
          "_spdisplays_pixels" : "1080 x 1920",
          "_spdisplays_projector" : "spdisplays_yes",
          "_spdisplays_resolution" : "1080 x 1920 @ 60.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_mirror" : "spdisplays_off",
          "spdisplays_online" : "spdisplays_yes",
          "spdisplays_pixelresolution" : "1080 x 1920",
          "spdisplays_resolution" : "1080 x 1920 @ 60.00Hz",
          "spdisplays_rotation" : 90
```

The EDID info wasn't helpful at all. I know it uses the [Kinect DK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/kinect-dk/) and I thought that might have some video out over USB but as far as I can tell it does not.

I am extremely confused.

What's going on where the HDMI port is somehow the input to the display? Is one of the USB connections lying to me and actually a display connection somehow? Is there a way to find that out without ripping out the display (it's bolted in there pretty tight)?

A friend suggested the ribbon cable is the display cable. I can't find any info on the motherboard though to convert it. The stickers on the motherboard look like they refer to Tempo models and not the motherboard itself.

[image]

Update: After some digging with a friend, I got into the BIOS and confirmed it's an LVDS display

[image]

My friend sent me a link to [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PW6N61N), but without the panel number, it's a big risk. If I boot into a normal Linux distro is there any way to pull the hardware info?

Comment: That's a pretty unusual device. I'm entirely talking out of my rear here, but *assuming* that's a board based off a laptop design (SODOMM says 'yes', heatsink and sata ports say no). This *might* indicate the monitor/panel could be eDP - and the HDMI port in the motherboard might pass *into* that.

Comment: I'd try to work back from the *display* and trace where its connected, and what the panel is might be of use, if they didn't just stick an entire off the shelf monitor

Comment: Just updated the post with some more info, but getting the display out is tough - it's bolted in with like a dozen very tight bolts and I'm lazy and hoping there's another way. What's eDP?

Comment: edit: it is an LVDS display, updating post

Comment: ah hah! Its possible your board has an LVDS out. eDP is a 'newer' panel interface than LVDS but 'essentially' is the same role. Now the next mystery is how the discrete card is passed through...

Comment: I don't think I have any other options to find the panel info than ripping it open - doing searches online for a 42" LVDS touch display turned up nothing.

Comment: Or finding someone else who has torn it down. The 'touch' is likely via USB, and is an overlay, you're looking for a 42 inch *panel* - and at that size its probably a 'small' TV panel, rather than a monitor... or see if you can use the HDMI in that's on the motherboard. Inefficient but might just work

Comment: good point, will expand the search. and you can use the HDMI on the motherboard but it displays content from ipadOS / iOS sideways/letterboxed. When plugging in my mac I have to force it to display correctly but it does work - just using the HDMI on the board is my backup plan but ideally I'd like to get my iphone/pad mirrored to it.

Comment: hm, other option would be to do it in software. Install another OS (on another drive! to be safe) and mirror that way